# BST with function ptr, How to add in extra argument?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

is there a way to pass in an extra argument to my function pointer in BST? I am trying to use BST inOrder to get value from a map<string, int>. this BST will be storing the key of the map.

The map will act as a database that uses date + time as the key. each BST will be created to store the date+time of each year and saved into another map (bstMap) which holds all bst. bstMap will use the year as key.

BST inOrder with function ptr.

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node.
{
    public:
        T m_key;
        Node<T> *m_left;
        Node<T> *m_right;

};

template <class T>
class BST
{
    typedef void(*funcPtr)(T &);

    public:
        BST();
        void Insert(T key);
        void Delete();
        void InOrder(void(*funcPtr)(T &)) const;
        void PreOrder(void(*funcPtr)(T &)) const;
        bool Search(T key);
        T MaxValue();
        bool IsEmpty() const {return m_root == nullptr;}
        void DeleteTree();

    private:
        Node<T> *m_root;

    protected:
        Node<T> *Insert(Node<T>* node, T key);
        Node<T> *Search(Node<T>* node, T key);
        void InOrder(Node<T>* node, void (*funcPtr)(T &)) const;
        void PreOrder(Node<T>* node, void (*funcPtr)(T &)) const;
        void DeleteTree(Node<T>* node);
        Node<T>* MaxValue(Node<T>* node);

};

template<class T>
BST<T>::BST(){
    m_root = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::InOrder(Node<T>* node, void(*funcPtr)(T &)) const
{
    if (node != nullptr)
    {
        InOrder(node-> m_left, funcPtr); //recursive call for node left

        funcPtr(node-> m_key);

        InOrder(node->m_right, funcPtr);
    }
}

template<class T>
 void BST<T>::InOrder(void(*funcPtr)(T &)){
  InOrder(m_root, funcPtr);
 }
```

This line of code is called from main.cpp which pass the user input year into the map to return the bst which stores all relevant keys.

```
void GetData(string& year, map<string, BST<string>>& bstMap)
{

    BST<string> bstKey = bstMap[year];
    bstKey.InOrder(&GetTotal);

}
```

So here is where i am stuck..

```
void GetTotal(string& key) <- how do i reference my database map here?
{
    cout<< key <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the entire node instead of just the key to the user-defined function?  Also, you would have more flexibility if the function were templated like this: `template<class T, class Fn>
void BST<T>::InOrder(Node<T>* node, Fn func) const` -- Then any callable type can be passed, not just a function pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hello paul, thank you for the tips. do you mean to pass in the entire node into the GetTotal func? the bst only contains string key.

Comment: *void GetTotal(string& key) <- how do i reference my database map here?* -- Where is this map stored?  Is it a global variable?  It would be a lot clearer if you had posted a [mcve].

Comment: The map is declared in main. I have read that it is not advisable to use global variable.

Comment: OK, then maybe implement the template differently, as suggested in the first comment where the function "pointer" is templated.  Then provide a lambda instead of a function pointer, and in the lambda capture, specify `[&]` to capture the map.  Or you could have provided a class that has `operator()` overloaded and passed that.  Basically, function pointers are just not smart enough to hold state as well as variables, while function objects and lambdas are much better options.

Comment: I havent read about lambda yet. Can you give me an example? Thank you so much for your patience and help, Paul.

Comment: The `InOrder` function you posted takes two arguments, but you call it with only one argument.  Is there another `InOrder` function that you didn't post?  I could post an answer, but this detail is missing.

Comment: GetData is called from main.cpp. the function which is passed into the inOrder, GetTotal() only has one argument, T&. Sorry i should have posted the full BST here. The InOrder seen is a recursive overload method called from InOrder(root)

Comment: Please post the single argument `InOrder` function.

Comment: Alright, its updated. Sorry about that i am using my phone to edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access variables outside of the `BST` template class (such as the map), then I advise changing your template to the following (assuming that `m_root` is a member variable of `BST<T>`, and that it is the root of tree):

```
template<class T, class Fn>
void BST<T>::InOrder(Fn funcPtr) const
{
    InOrder(m_root, fn); 
}

template<class T, class Fn>
void BST<T>::InOrder(Node<T>* node, Fn funcPtr) const
{
   if (node)
   {
      InOrder(node-> m_left, funcPtr); //recursive call for node left
      funcPtr(node-> m_key);
      InOrder(node->m_right, funcPtr);
   }
}
```

Then this way, you can pass a function object or lambda that knows about the map.  In the case below, a lambda function is used:

```
void GetData(string& year, map<string, BST<string>>& bstMap)
{
    BST<string> bstKey = bstMap[year];
    bstKey.InOrder([&](std::string& key) { std::cout << bstMap[key] << "\n"; });
}
```

The above provides a lambda that captures the passed-in `map` parameter.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Paul. Appreciate your patience hipe you have a great day ahead!

Comment: Hi Paul, i tried to add template<class T, class Fn> but the compiler give an error wrong number of template arguments. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a64ab512c09ec919).  Ignore the seg fault errors, and this uses dummy data and the tree isn't set up.  But the point is that the code compiles with no errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hello. Could you please have a look at [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257710/c-implementation-of-depth-first-search) for me? I would greatly appreciate your input on it.